# How to Clone an Array With a Removed Element?

Tags: javascript

I've searched up this question, and everywhere people seem to recommend to use array.splice(). However, splice is inplace, and, for example, in my javascript console editor.

[image: Array splicing]

Everywhere I seem to search, people say that splice does NOT mutate the original array, but that is clearly not the case. Now, I'm sure I will find another way to do what I want, but what is the proper way to make a copy of a piece of an array without affecting the original array?

Comment: slice does not mutate the original array. 
splice mutates the array.
The names are bit similar

Comment: First line on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): "The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place." You need to use `slice()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), see below:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(x);

let sliced = x.slice(0, 2);

console.log(x);
console.log(sliced);
```

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included) where begin and end represent the index of items in that array. **The original array will not be modified.**

Comment: Oh my god. Wow. I read slice as splice for some reason, and I kept trying to figure out why everyone was recommending to use it. My brain just sees things

Comment: You're not alone @semiprocoder :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the array using the `spread operator` and then you can use `splice` or whatever.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let newArr = [...arr];

console.log(newArr);

// newArr.splice(......)
```

Comment: Why do you pass it in a Set? That will remove duplicate values, which is not what OP is doing.

Comment: good call, has been revised